# can we enable Moving and Zooming google maps camera after first zoom android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Google maps in a fragment. I'm facing some problem when I Zoom and move the google maps camera It's not moving, in every 1000 milliseconds it updating continuously. I searched for it "how to freely move and zoom google maps camera for the 2nd time". second time user should be able to zoom in zoom out and can move the Google maps camera. Below is my code I want this on `MapReady()` method If possible. Let me know your thoughts.

```java
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location)
{
   lastLocation = location;
   LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
   mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, works fine for me

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location)
    {
        lastLocation = location;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng ).zoom(14).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
```

Comment: Hi Frendy, Thanks for your response. But this is the same as what I did before. I want the same act in OnMapReady section